# Убрать системный Toast

Tags: android, android-studio

Использую следующий код:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mVoiceInputTv;
    private Button mSpeakBtn;
    private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mVoiceInputTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
        mSpeakBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        mSpeakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startVoiceInput();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startVoiceInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hello, How can I help you?");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

При запуске на устройстве появляется сообщение о том, что аудиозапись будет отправлена в Google и т.д. 
 Как это убрать?

P.S. Устройство HTC One M8 ds, Android 6.0, HTC Sense 7.0

Answer (score 2):

Это невозможно. Вы не можете скрыть системные Toast сообщения, также как у Вас нет доступа к системным View (исключение разве что для рутованных устройств). При этом на рутованных устройствах Вы можете скрыть этот Toast, однако воспрепятствовать отправке аудиозаписи в Google всё равно нельзя.

[Ссылка на ответ на аналогичный вопрос на англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50692655/4898850).